# Running an instance of node.js using command prompt

Tags: asp.net, node.js, bootstrap-typeahead

am trying to learn ***asp.net 5*** and I am following a tutorial in that is a beginners course. There is module of how to create an aspnet web template on a local machine and getting it running. Right now am stuck on running the instance using the ***commmand promp***t to get the local server running. would like help for you fellas. the** "dnx web" **command is outputting this error below:
***[running the dnx web commnand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lljja.png)***

while trying to run the command that comes with creation on the site: dotnet run brings me this message below. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xQDn.png)
kindly help